# Warning when combining textgreek and hyperref package

Tags: hyperref, greek

I am trying to include Greek letters into a section title. The MWE below produces the output desired, but also the warning

> Glyph not defined in PD1 encoding,(hyperref) removing `\textalpha'

and the same for `\textgamma` but interestingly not for `\textbeta`. Obviously `hyperref` is causing the problem, however it is required.

```
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{\textalpha\textbeta\textgamma}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the unicode option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{\textalpha\textbeta\textgamma}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is that MWE really defaulting to that section format?

Comment: @Davislor the screenshot is from the bookmarks/outline (in sumatra) , to show that hyperref handled everything correctly with the unicode option.